# Do all verbs form the conjunctive II with an umlaut?

Tags: subjunctive, conjugation, umlaut

As far I know we normally form the conjunctive II with the preterite (past) form of the verb. Coming from the preterite, we replace *a* with *ä*, *u* with *ü* and *o* with *ö* and also add an extra *e* if possible. For example:

1. gehen – gingen – sind gegangen.
   Präteritum: Ich ging
   Konjuktiv II: Ich ginge
2. arbeiten – arbeiteten – haben gearbeitet
   Präteritum: Ich arbeitete
   Konjuktiv II : Ich arbeitete (as there is no *a, o, u* to replace and it has already got an *e* at the end)

According to this rule besuchen and machen should be conjugated as following:

1. besuchen – besuchten – haben besucht
   Präteritum: Ich besuchte
   Konjuktiv II: Ich besüchte – which seems to be wrong; the correct conjugation is *besuchte*.
2. machen – machten – haben gemacht
   Präteritum: Ich machte
   Konjuktiv II: Ich mächte –  wrong, correct conjugation is *machte*.

Could anyone please explain why are we not replacing *u* with *ü* in besuchen and *a* with *ä* in machen?

Comment: @Carsten Schulz: The allophones of _-ch-_ are not an issue. Consider _brechen_, _brach_, _bräche_, _gebrochen_; or _kriechen_, _kroch_, _kröche_, _gekrochen_.

Comment: @Thanks. I was looking for examples in my head, but did not find any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule you cited only applies to strong verbs (also called irregular verbs):

> lesen: las, läse
>   biegen: bog, böge
>   schaffen: schuf, schüfe
>   laufen: lief, liefe

It is not applicable to weak verbs (regular verbs), which form the past tenses with *-t-*. For them, the *Konjunktiv II* is normally identical to the *Präteritum*:

> machen: machte, machte
>   besuchen: besuchte, besuchte

(Note that the rule does not cover all cases of strong verbs, either; e.g., *sterben* has forms *starb* and *stürbe*.)

Comment: Although one might argue that *stürbe* is nothing else than an ‘even stronger’ umlaut ;)